# Change range of chart in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts

I am simply trying to add a range to my charts that starts from midnight and goes until the end of the day. The data fits in the middle. I want there to be blanks in between the time when there is no data. I can't seem to inflate the axis to accept this. What can I do with the standard chart control in Visual Studio to fix this? thanks!

```
 private void GetChartData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PLUM_DEVConnectionString"].ToString()))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spselectByGroup", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            string testing = null;


            //string testing = null;
            for (int x = 0; x<4; x++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                if (x==0) {
                    testing = "ES-D3-HST";
                } else if (x==1)
                {
                    testing = "ES-D3-EVT";
                } else if (x==2)
                {
                    testing = "ES-D3-SAN";
                } else if (x==3)
                {
                    testing = DBNull.Value.ToString();
                }
                Series srs = new Series();
                if (testing.Equals(DBNull.Value.ToString()))
                {
                    testing = "NULL";
                    srs = new Series(testing);
                    testing = DBNull.Value.ToString(); ;
                } else { srs = new Series(testing); }


            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@group", testing);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                Series line = new Series();
                line.ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
                line.MarkerColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                string blah = null;
                while (reader.Read()) {

                    blah = reader["DateOf"].ToString();
                    blah = blah.Substring(0, 10);
                srs.Points.AddXY(reader["DateOf"].ToString(), reader["Result"]);
                    //line.Points.AddXY(0, 2500);


                }
                string beginning = " 12:00:00 AM";
                string end = " 11:59:59 PM";
                //System.DateTime xhello = new DateTime(2016, 10, 25, 12, 00, 00);
                line.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
                Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
                Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
                Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = 1000;
                line.Points.AddXY(blah+beginning, 2500);
                line.Points.AddXY(blah+end, 2500);
                Chart1.Series.Add(srs);
                Chart1.Legends.Add(testing);
                Chart1.Series.Add(line);
                //Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;


                conn.Close();
            }
            //Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = DateTime.Parse("10/24/2016").ToOADate();
            //Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = DateTime.Parse("10/26/2016").ToOADate();


        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Seeing neither your data nor the result doesn't really help us..

Comment: ![Here](http://i.imgur.com/34z2aUo.png) data comes in minutes of the day

Comment: @TaW whoops needed to at the @